# side menu view is not shown

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have a side menu in a controller ..

i'm dealing with it like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sidemenuconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  @IBAction func sidmenu(_ sender: Any) {

    if isSidemenuHidden{
        sidemenuconstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }else {
        sidemenuconstraint.constant = -284
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    isSidemenuHidden = !isSidemenuHidden

}
```

and here is a screenshot of the scene:

[image]

[image]
its working when i click .. the problem is that the side menu view is behind the other views.. i cannot access the buttons in it .. and the view is not shown .. the buttons will only appears and can't press them!

[image]

how to solve this?

Comment: i don't see any button in your view hierarchy of which `IBAction` is connected to `sidmenu`. Consider clarifying this.

Comment: @RatulSharker just posted another picture.. but the button is connected properly to the sidemenu and it will be shown and hidden when clicked .. the only problem is that i can't access it .. it seems as it was behind .. and the view's background also not shown

Comment: will you consider adding the output view & specify exactly which button's IBAction is `@IBAction func sidmenu(_ sender: Any)` among those buttons ?

Comment: jus added @RatulSharker

Comment: @mrs.bassim, In your storyboard, drag the SideMenu and put it on top of Bar. changing view hierarchy  may solve your problem

Comment: @ImrulKayes tried but didn't work :(

Comment: could you provide github link of your project, if its not private?

Comment: as @ImrulKayes said drag `sideMenu` and put it on top bar or navBar _**then**_ drag it and put in the last in hierarchy again ( below tableView ).

Comment: @arash didn't solve it :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to change the zIndex of the menu, make an outlet of the sideMenu view and try `yourSideMenuViewOutlet.layer.zPosition = 5`. This can also be added directly via storyboard in the "identity inspector" at the "user defined runtime attributes" section.